# redirect all sub urls to main domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, indexing, subdomain

I have recently updated my forum url and wondering how can I redirect old sub urls to the main domain only...
I mean I have sub urls under `www.mydomain.com/vb` and many other sub urls under `www.mydomain.com/vm`

And what I want this to redirect all what under both `www.mydomain.com/vb` and `www.mydomain.com/vm` to my main domian `www.mydomain.com` so I don't loss visitors in this case...

any idea how to do that?

**P.S. I have over 55,000 pages indexed... and wondering if this way would make me loss my indexed pages on google or not!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the following since the above codes didn't do the full job...

```
<?php

header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.com' ) ;

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write below information in .htaccess at the root folder.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^vm/(.*)$ / [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^vb/(.*)$ / [L,R=301]
```

For more options have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work for me... maybe I should have mentioned that there is a fixed sub directory after vm and vb like this: `www.mydomain.com/vm/threads/` and `www.mydomain.com/vb/threads/`... would that change anything in your code in this case??

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 (or more) solutions:

1.Adding this lines to your www htaccess (example.com/.htaccess)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^vb/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^vm/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

2.Adding this lines to Each folder (vm & vb) htaccess file (example.com/vm/.htaccess & example.com/vb/.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but none working even though they look decent ways. The thing is that they are .php urls already mod_rewritten under `vb/threads/` and that could be the reason why it doesn't work